# Postgres with recursive query with multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I need to find all the child items of a parent item recursively in postgres.

I have a table structure like this:

```
items
-----
id

modifiers
---------
id

item_modifiers
--------------
id
item_id
modifier_id

modifier_items
--------------
id
item_id
modifier_id
```

Item has_many `child_modifiers` through `item_modifiers`
Modifier has_many `child_items` through `modifier_items`.

So basically the hierarchy goes like this: `item -> item_modifiers -> modifier -> modifier_items -> item`

I have this but not working. Not sure what to change.

```
    WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, path) AS (
      SELECT "items".id, ARRAY["items".id]
      FROM items
      WHERE "items".id ='#{top_level_item.id}'
    UNION ALL
      SELECT #{table_name}.id, path || #{table_name}.id
      FROM search_tree
      INNER JOIN modifier_items
      ON "search_tree".id = "modifier_items".item_id
      WHERE "modifier_items".modifier_id IN (
        SELECT "modifiers".id
        FROM modifiers
        INNER JOIN item_modifiers ON "modifiers".id = "item_modifiers".modifier_id
        WHERE "item_modifiers".item_id = "search_tree".id
      )
      WHERE NOT #{table_name}.id = ANY(path)
  )
  SELECT id FROM search_tree ORDER BY path
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show what result you want to get? I'm not sure that this part is necessary: `WHERE "modifier_items".modifier_id IN`.

Comment: I am using that line to make sure only the modifiers that have that item in the joint table will be queried.